# Comparison colors, output functions in SASS

Tags: sublime-text

I need something like this:

> I'm using SASS to create a parent theme that has say 10 child themes. Those child themes simply vary in color and BG texture. So I have a couple variables set for a primary color, secondary color and tertiary color. All shades and variations are done in the original theme via color functions off one of those colors.
>
> So for instance, I need a BG shade slightly different from the primary color - and I have what the original design calls for, so I'm basically looking for the algorithm that generates the color difference between those two - i.e. my request.

https://github.com/arc90/sass-color-picker/issues/3

Is there a tool like this?

Comment: Are you specifically wanting it to be a sublime text plugin?

Comment: It would be nice but it can be as e.g. web app. I've spent hours on searching and I found only this: http://sassme.arc90.com/
Unfortunately I can't input second color.